# Access current tab page components from script.js mozilla addon-sdk

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have just started learning firefox addon development using Addon-SDK. I am developing an addon that has a button. When i click on that button a panel displays and it loads a page in panel.
The code for panel is as below:

```
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var panel = panels.Panel({
      contentURL: self.data.url("mypage.html"),
      height:380,
      width:300
});
```

Now i want to access components(eg. input type text) of current tab page of the browser from "script.js" file that is included in "mypage.html". I cant post images as i have only 6 reputation. Please help.

Comment: There's some simple examples in the Addon SDK documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port - about half way down there's an example for communication between a panel and a pageMod ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod ) script

Comment: @JaromandaX you couldn't understand that i dont want to access page components from main.js i want to access the components from script.js when a button is clicked that is placed in mypage.html loaded on panel.

Comment: I understand exactly what you said you wanted to do, and I gave you the link to find out how to do it - here's a link that will take you directly where you need to be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#Accessing_port_in_the_Add-on_Script

Answer (score 0):

In `index.js` (or `main.js`):

```
panel.port.emit('TAG', 'MSG');
```

sends an `'MSG'` message on `panel`'s port, tagged as `'TAG'`.

In `script.js` (read further to understand what this file is):

```
self.port.on('TAG', function ( msg ) {
  alert(msg);
});
```

listens to all messages on script's dedicated port (here a port provided by `panel`, to which `script.js` is attached), which are tagged as `'TAG'`.

And backwards: `self.port.emit` in `script.js`, `panel.port.on` in `index.js`...

***You need to take this approach*** in order to communicate between main add-on scripts and panel's injected content scripts.

***Also! In order to make it work you will need to separate HTML file (your `mypage.html`) from `javascript` inside of it:***

```
var panel = require('sdk/panel').Panel({
  contentURL:        self.data.url('mypage.html'), // var self = require("sdk/self")
  contentScriptFile: self.data.url('some-content-script.js')
});
```

So in your case:

1. Access the tab from within `index.js` and get your data.
2. Send that data to panel's `some-content-script.js`, using panel's in-built port (`panel.port.emit('TAG', 'DATA')`).
3. Intercept that data in `some-content-script.js` (which is attached to `panel`) using panel's in-built port (`self.port.on('TAG', function interceptor (data) {}`).
4. Do what you want with `data` variable (containing `'DATA'` string), inside `interceptor` function.

You can also attach multiple `.js` content script files to your `panel` like this:

```
var panel = require('sdk/panel').Panel({
  contentURL:         self.data.url('mypage.html'),
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url('script_1.js'),
                      self.data.url('script_2.js')]
});
```

On `index.js`'s side `panel`'s port is `panel.port`, whilst on content scripts' side `panel`'s port is known as `self.port`.

`...port.on` (and `...port.once`) is for intercepting messages from port, whilst `...port.emit` is for posting messages on port.